# CSS - Footer to stay at bottom of the page

Tags: php, html, css

I have a footer in my page and it although it goes at the bottom  - it stays at the bottom of the screen and then is fixed there, so if i scroll down it stays half way down page.

below is what I have currently although I have tried loads of different things and searched on Google a lot!!

```
#footer {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 1rem;
background-color: #00608F;
text-align: center;
}
```

Footer appears at bottom to start with but when I scroll
[image: Footer appears at bottom to start with but when I scroll]
Its stays in the same position...
[image: Its stays in the same position...]

Answer (score 1):

You should use `position:fixed`

```css
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #00608F;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
  Footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks that does work in terms meaning the footer remains at the bottom, however I meant to say and will update the same that I want to footer to go to the very bottom of the page and not to appear on the page the whole time only when they are at the very bottom of the page.